# How to solve local variable error with forloop in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-3.8

**Info**: I want to get data from context. The context data is coming from for loop function.

**Problem**: I am getting this `UnboundLocalError local variable 'context' referenced before assignment`

```
def CurrentMatch(request, match_id):
    match = Match.objects.get(id=match_id)
    match_additional = MatchAdditional.objects.get(match=match)
    innings = match_additional.current_innings

    recent = Score.objects.filter(match=match).filter(innings=innings).order_by('over_number')[::-1][:1]

    for score in recent:
        context = {
            "ball_number": score.ball_number,
            "over_number": score.over_number,
        }

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context))
```

Comment: it is because 'recent' is empty from object.filter.
please check if 'recent' is empty.

Comment: can you explain it how can i check recent is empty?

Comment: easy, 'if recent:', this means recent is not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this  :

```
def CurrentMatch(request, match_id):
    match = Match.objects.get(id=match_id)
    match_additional = MatchAdditional.objects.get(match=match)
    innings = match_additional.current_innings

    recent = Score.objects.filter(match=match).filter(innings=innings).order_by('over_number')[::-1][:1]
    if recent:
        for score in recent:
            context = {
                "ball_number": score.ball_number,
                "over_number": score.over_number,
            }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({}))
```

Answer (score 0):

it happened because recent queryset is emtpy. use this snippet:

```py
def CurrentMatch(request, match_id):
    match = Match.objects.get(id=match_id)
    match_additional = MatchAdditional.objects.get(match=match)
    innings = match_additional.current_innings

    recent = Score.objects.filter(match=match).filter(innings=innings).order_by('over_number')[::-1][:1]
    if len(recent) > 0:
        for score in recent:
            context = {
                "ball_number": score.ball_number,
                "over_number": score.over_number,
            }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({}))
```

with this part of code `len(recent)` you can check whether the queryset has objects or not.

Comment: your code is getting this issue `'list' object has no attribute 'exists'
`

Comment: I edited my snippet check it again. @afi